# Ruby OAuth2.0: client credential type has unsupported client authentication method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, net-http

I am using [OAuth2](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2) gem, for making a client_credential authentication. My code is as below,

```
require 'oauth2'
client = OAuth2::Client.new("my_client_id", "my_client_secret", :site => "my_site_url", :token_url => "oauth2/token")
client.client_credentials.get_token
```

When I execute above code block, it respond with below error,

```
OAuth2::Error (invalid_client: Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method))
{
  "error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method)",
  "error_hint":"The OAuth 2.0 Client supports client authentication method "client_secret_basic", but method "client_secret_post" was requested. 
  You must configure the OAuth 2.0 client's "token_endpoint_auth_method" value to accept "client_secret_post".","status_code":401}
```

I checked the using 'net/http' library, and my `client_id` & `client_secrets` are valid and working.

The only problem I see is with the authentication method as said in hint of above message,

```
The OAuth 2.0 Client supports client authentication method "client_secret_basic", but method "client_secret_post" was requested. You must configure the OAuth 2.0 client's "token_endpoint_auth_method" value to accept "client_secret_post"
```

What I want to know is?

1. How `OAuth2` gem decide on using client_secret_post vs client_secret_basic? I mean How can I request with client_secret_basic in OAuth2 gem?
2. If not above then, How should I specify token_endpoint_auth_method to accpet client_secret_post?

Comment: There's a missing quote. Did you missed it while pasting in stackoverflow or in code please check

Comment: Missed it here only, its there in code.

Comment: If you use a middleware it probably use the `client_secret_basic` to make a request you only need to change the middleware configuration

Answer (score 1):

OK, so finally I cleared these points.

1. OAuth2 gem does make a request to OAuth server with --token_endpoint_auth_method set to 'client_secret_post'.
2. While registering an client with OAuth server we will have to set token_endpoint_auth_method to 'client_secret_post', so that it will work.

In my case I was using Hydra, so I used below command to create a client:

```
hydra clients create --endpoint <OAuth server url> --id CLIENT_ID --secret CLIENT_SECRET \
--token-endpoint-auth-method 'client_secret_post' -g client_credentials
```

Now, using these CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET with oauth2 works.

But still one point which is unclear - can I make a request with **token_endpoint_auth_method** set to **client_secret_basic** using oauth2 gem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue.

Please add or change this client option setting in your client code.

```
:auth_scheme => :basic_auth
```

The default settings is below.

```
:auth_scheme => :request_body
```

I have excerpted a part of the OAuth2::Client code.

Please check it.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'logger'

module OAuth2
  # The OAuth2::Client class
  class Client # rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
    attr_reader :id, :secret, :site
    attr_accessor :options
    attr_writer :connection

    # @option opts [Symbol] :auth_scheme (:basic_auth) HTTP method to use to authorize request (:basic_auth or :request_body)

    def initialize(client_id, client_secret, options = {}, &block)
      opts = options.dup
      @id = client_id
      @secret = client_secret
      @site = opts.delete(:site)
      ssl = opts.delete(:ssl)
      @options = {:authorize_url    => '/oauth/authorize',
                  :token_url        => '/oauth/token',
                  :token_method     => :post,
                  :auth_scheme      => :request_body,  # <-- Here !!!
                  :connection_opts  => {},
                  :connection_build => block,
                  :max_redirects    => 5,
                  :raise_errors     => true}.merge(opts)
      @options[:connection_opts][:ssl] = ssl if ssl
    end
```

Sample snippet is here https://gist.github.com/mtoshi/cd74f57631805fb1b2290137f58dac9f

Answer (score 0):

If you use a middleware it probably use the `client_secret_basic` to make a request you only need to change the configuration of that something similar to this. I use `nextauth` middleware.

```
client: {
      token_endpoint_auth_method: 'client_secret_post'
    }
```