# Ruby Oauth2.0: client_secret_post not working with ory hydra

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, token, hydra

I am trying to get a Ruby Oauth2.0 client talking with the Ory Hydra docker-compose 5 minute demo.   I am stuck on the client app's authentication code exchange for the token.   LOG is below.   Looks like the main problem is the following "hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password".

DEBUG LOG FROM HYDRA SERVER

```
time="2019-06-04T21:32:09Z" level=info msg="started handling request" method=POST remote="172.19.0.2:35482" request=/oauth2/token
hydra_1

time="2019-06-04T21:32:09Z" level=error msg="An error occurred" debug="crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password" description="Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method)" error=invalid_client
hydra_1

time="2019-06-04T21:32:09Z" level=info msg="completed handling request" measure#hydra/public: http://127.0.0.1:4444/.latency=92931900 method=POST remote="172.19.0.2:35482" request=/oauth2/token status=401 text_status=Unauthorized took=92.9319ms
```

I've read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529838/ruby-oauth2-0-client-credential-type-has-unsupported-client-authentication-meth) and it would appear this 'is' possible.

Here is how I register my client 'test-app9' in hydra:

```
docker-compose -f quickstart.yml exec hydra hydra clients create --endpoint http://127.0.0.1:4445 --id test-app9 --secret secret--skip-tls-verify --grant-types authorization_code,refresh_token,client_credentials,implicit --response-types token,code,id_token --scope profile --callbacks http://127.0.0.1:8088/auth/callback --token-endpoint-auth-method client_secret_post -g client_credentials
```

I can indeed see the client appearing in the postgres DB from the docker-compose demo.  The password 'secret' is hashed in the DB.

Here is my single Sinatra file acting as the Oauth2.0 client:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'oauth2'
require 'json'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

# If you add your authentication in the header then use ~Sclient_secret_basic~T
# If you add your authentication details in the post use ~Sclient_secret_post~T

def client
  OAuth2::Client.new('test-app9',
                     'secret',
#                     'c2VjcmV0',
                     :site => "http://127.0.0.1:4445",
                     :logger => Logger.new('example.log'),
                     :authorize_url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/oauth2/auth",
                     :token_url => "http://hydra:4444/oauth2/token")
end

set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "views") }
set :run, true
set :port, 80

get "/" do
  erb :index
end

get '/auth' do
  authorization_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :response_type => "code", :scope => "profile", :state => "pqrst1234")
  puts "Redirecting to URL: #{authorization_url.inspect}"
  redirect authorization_url
end

get '/auth/callback' do
  begin
    access_token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :client_id => "test-app9", :client_secret => 'secret', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'basic_auth_header', 'client_id' => 'test-app9', 'client_secret' => 'c2VjcmV0'} )
    api_url = "/me.json"
    me = JSON.parse(access_token.get(api_url).body)
    erb "<p>Your data:\n#{me.inspect}</p>"
  rescue OAuth2::Error => e
    erb %(<p>Wassup #{$!}</p><p><a href="/auth">Retry</a></p>)
  end
end

get '/auth/failure' do
  erb "<h1>Authentication Failed:</h1><h3>message:<h3> <pre>#{params}</pre>"
end

def redirect_uri(path = '/auth/callback', query = nil)
  uri = URI.parse(request.url)
  uri.path  = path
  uri.query = query
  uri.to_s
end

__END__
```

So some interesting notes:

1. It apparently does not matter what secret I initiate the OAuth2 client with.  I can use 'secret' or the base64 encoded 'c2VjcmV0' string.   Either way I get up to the token exchange portion.
2. I was shotgunning this and ended up putting the client_id and the client_secret in what I believe is the proper way to set in the headers as well as the body.

I have tried many variations of this.   Can't seem to get the correct syntax that the [author of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529838/ruby-oauth2-0-client-credential-type-has-unsupported-client-authentication-meth) apparently succeeded with OR I'm hitting a bug (doubtful).

Anyone able to help here?

UPDATE
Fixed this myself.  Problem was syntax issue when creating my client 'app'.  This is the corrected version.

```
docker-compose -f quickstart.yml exec hydra hydra clients create --endpoint http://127.0.0.1:4445 --id test-app10 --secret secret --skip-tls-verify --grant-types authorization_code,refresh_token,client_credentials,implicit --response-types token,code,id_token --scope profile --callbacks http://127.0.0.1:8088/auth/callback --token-endpoint-auth-method client_secret_post -g client_credentials
```

Comment: Fixed.  Hydra uses Bcrypt to encode your clients password in the Postgres DB.  I bcrypt'd my 'secret' manually and overwrote the existing one in the Postgres DB.   Ta da.. it works now.   The only think I can think of is that I made a mistake when creating the client to begin with and now that I'm looking at my code... Yup.. I did.    In any case, what you have above is a 'working' example of a Ruby Oauth2 client talking with a Hydra Oauth2 server & consent/login service.   There were some considerations on the docker networking side.  Make sure all containers are bound to the local host.

Comment: Hey, do you happen to know any Ruby, Omniauth or similar working implementation with ORY Hydra? Thx!

Comment: @quackduck can you please create an answer from your comment and accept that answer, so that this issue has a fix? thx!